# Replacing JRequest (deprecated) with JInput

Tags: joomla-3.x, jrequest, deprecated

I believe `JRequest` is deprecated and should be replaced with `Jinput`, however when I change the following code:

```
$limit = JRequest::getInt('limit', $app->get('list_limit'));
$this->setState('list.limit', $limit);         
$limitstart = JRequest::getInt('limitstart', 'limitstart', 0);
```

to this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$limit = jinput::getInt('limit', $app->get('list_limit'));
$this->setState('list.limit', $limit);         
$limitstart = jinput::getInt('limitstart', 'limitstart', 0);
```

It doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason why you're code isn't working is because you haven't called the `$jinput` variable correctly. Also, `getInt` is not a static function, therefore should **not** be called statically.

So replace this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$limit = jinput::getInt('limit', $app->get('list_limit'));
$this->setState('list.limit', $limit);         
$limitstart = jinput::getInt('limitstart', 'limitstart', 0);
```

with this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$limit = $jinput->getInt('limit', $app->get('list_limit'));
$this->setState('list.limit', $limit);         
$limitstart = $jinput->getInt('limitstart', 'limitstart', 0);
```

I'm surprised you didn't get any errors when viewing the site. So in future, please set **Error Reporting** on your Global Configuration to **Development**