# Article id from category view

Tags: joomla-3.x, id

I want to print the Article id next to the title and I need to get an article id. I used this code:

```
$article_id = JRequest::getVar('id');
echo $article_id;
```

And it works great when I'm in article view (article layout). If I try to use this code in the category view (blog layout), I get the category id instead of the article id. How can I get article id in blog layout?

Thanks in advance!
Regards, 
Midhat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you should access the article's object id property. By the way, do note that [**`JRequest` is deprecated**](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/replacing-jrequest-deprecated-with-jinput).

For the article, in your article template you can add next to the article's title the:

```
echo $this->item->id;
```

For the category blog title, we are actually talking about the same (as the blog layout is looping through the articles of a category, so you still have access to each article object properties. However the difference here is that the category blog article title layout is handled via the `JLayouts`.

You will need to override the following file:

```
/layouts/joomla/content/blog_style_default_item_title.php
```

Inside there you can find the article object in the `$displayData` variable. So for the id:

```
echo $displayData->id;
```