# PHP7.2 Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php7, jrequest

I got this notice when I changed a Joomla website from PHP 5.6 to PHP7.2

"Only variables should be passed by reference in ... on line 116"
The second line is line 116

```
    if($this->isViewExcluded($article)) {
        if($this->isArticleExcluded(JRequest::getInt('id', 0))) {
            $this->createButton($article);
```

Same for line 257
The third line beneath

```
function getArticleLink(&$article)
{
        $u =& JFactory::getURI();
        return $u->toString();
}
```

I read [Replacing JRequest (deprecated) with JInput](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/replacing-jrequest-deprecated-with-jinput) when I got the notice and tried a lot with the solution given on that page (and other pages), but unfortunately no success.

Does anyone has a solution to make this work in PHP7.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function argument contains a `&` at the beginning, it requires a variable to be passed by reference rather than referencing an object value directly.

So you'll need to replace this:

```
if ($this->isArticleExcluded(JRequest::getInt('id', 0))) {

}
```

with this:

```
$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id');

if ($this->isArticleExcluded($id)) {

}
```

Also, you can remove the `&` before `JFactory`